# Ninject injection chain isolation

Tags: c#, .net, binding, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm working on an application that is split over multiple assemblies. Each of the assemblies provides Interfaces to the outside world, instances are generated via Ninject-based factories.

Ah well, ***let there be Code***. This is from the executing Assembly.

```
public class IsolationTestModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        ServiceFactory sf = new ServiceFactory();
        Bind<IService>().ToMethod(context=>sf.CreatService()).InSingletonScope();
    }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new IsolationTestModule());
        IService service = kernel.Get<IService>();
    }
}
```

The `ServiceFactory` also relies on `Ninject`, but has its own `Kernel` and its own `Module`:

```
public interface IService
{
    void Idle();
}

public interface IDependantService
{
    void IdleGracefully();
}

public class ServiceImpl : IService
{
    [Inject]
    public IDependantService DependantService { get; set; }

    public void Idle() 
    {
        DependantService.IdleGracefully();
    }
}

public class DependantServiceImpl : IDependantService
{
    public void IdleGracefully() { }
}

public class ServiceFactory
{
    private IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel(new SuppliesModule());

    public IService CreatService()
    {
        return _kernel.Get<IService>();
    }
}

public class SuppliesModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IService>().To<ServiceImpl>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IDependantService>().To<DependantServiceImpl>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

**What actually happens :** All's well until the `ServiceFactory` has completed to build the `ServiceImpl`-instance. In the next step, the ***application's*** `kernel` tries to resolve `ServiceImpl` dependencies via `IsolationTestModule` and - of course - fails with an exception (no binding available, type `IDependantService` is not self-bindable). In my understanding the ***factory***'s kernel should do that...
Actually I never knew Ninject was that eager to resolve dependencies even in those instances it did not immediately create, which surely opens up new horizons to me ;-)

To temporarily solve this, I change the `ServiceImpl` to Constructor based injection as depicted below:

```
public class ServiceImpl : IService
{
    public IDependantService DependantService { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public ServiceImpl(IDependantService dependantService)
    {
        DependantService = dependantService;
    }

    public void Idle() 
    {
        DependantService.IdleGracefully();
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, I would prefer a solution that does not force me to change my Injection strategy. Does anyone have an idea how I can separate the Injection chains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations are correct. Ninject will do property injection for objects created by `ToMethod`. Also your solution to use constructor injection is the right way to go. Constructor injection is the perfered way to use Ninject anyway. Property Injection should  be used for optional dependencies only.

What you should consider is to use just one kernel. It is very unusual to use multiple kernel instances in an application.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Remo. In fact I'm creating three completely independent Assemblies. Those - coincidentally, you might say - have the habit of using Ninject and may be used simultaneously. Each one uses Ninject **internally**, but exposes Factory classes and Interfaces to the outside only. I have already switched to constructor injection so, this is basically solved.